# How to get an image to pass variable to next page using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, image

I'm making a game where I need the user's name and selected image to pass to the next page. The code I've used does this for the name and I think the image information has also been passed, but the image doesn't show on the second page, it just shows a broken icon.

This must be done using only JS/Jquery.

This is the HTML - I've used radio buttons for this and set the value as the image path.

```
<div class="introbox">
  <div class="introtext"><h1>Pick an Avatar:</h1></div>
  <div class="avatarselection">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="test"  checked />
      <img src="Elements/images/Avatar1.png" alt="Blue Planet Avatar" class="Avatar Planet" value="Elements/images/Avatar1.png"/></label>
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" />
    <img src="Elements/images/Avatar2.png" alt="Pink Spaceman Avatar" class="Avatar Spaceman" value="Elements/images/Avatar2.png"/></label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="test" />
    <img src="Elements/images/Avatar3.png" alt="Multicolour Spaceship Avatar" class="Avatar Spaceship" value="Elements/images/Avatar3.png" /></label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="test" />
    <img src="Elements/images/Avatar4.png" alt="Earth Planet Avatar" class="Avatar Earth" value="Elements/images/Avatar4.png" /></label>
    
  </div>
```

This is the JS/JQuery I'm trying.

```
$(".enter").on("click", setStorage)

function setStorage(){

    //save name input
    let usernameval = $(".name").val();
    localStorage.setItem('usernameval', usernameval);
    //save avatar input
    let avatarval = $("input[type='radio']:checked").val();
    localStorage.setItem('avatarval', avatarval);
    //shows message name & avatar are saved
    $(".submitted").text("Thanks " + usernameval);
}

window.onload = function(){
    let getName = localStorage.getItem('usernameval');
    $(".username").html(getName);

    let getAvatar = localStorage.getItem('avatarval');
    $(".useravatar").html("<img src=" + getAvatar + "/>");
}
```

This is what's happening, there should be the user selected avatar above the name.

[image: should be the user selected avatar above the name]

Comment: what is the actual url being fetched as seen in the devtools network tab?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I see that you get the Value of the Radio Checkbox, yet when I review the HTML, there is no `value` attribute set. So it will be a `null` value every time. Please add `value="Elements/images/Avatar1.png"` or select the Source from the next element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

**HTML**

```
<div class="introbox">
  <div class="introtext">
    <h1>Pick an Avatar:</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="avatarselection">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="test" checked value="Elements/images/Avatar1.png" />
      <img src="Elements/images/Avatar1.png" alt="Blue Planet Avatar" class="Avatar Planet" />
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="test" value="Elements/images/Avatar2.png" />
      <img src="Elements/images/Avatar2.png" alt="Pink Spaceman Avatar" class="Avatar Spaceman" />
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="test" value="Elements/images/Avatar3.png" />
      <img src="Elements/images/Avatar3.png" alt="Multicolour Spaceship Avatar" class="Avatar Spaceship" />
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="test" value="Elements/images/Avatar4.png" />
      <img src="Elements/images/Avatar4.png" alt="Earth Planet Avatar" class="Avatar Earth" />
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `value` attribute is only assigned to Form Elements. You can assign it to your Image Element, yet this is bad practice. Moving the `value` to the `input` allows you to call `.val()` and get the proper value back.

Comment: Thank you, I see where I've went wrong there! You've fixed my issue!